# I'm using django-extra-views to have 2 forms on 1 page. How should I handle custom logic in form_valid?

Tags: python, django, forms

Here is my views.py code

```
class AttackItemInline(InlineFormSetFactory):
    model = AttackItem
    fields = ['attack_used','attack_image']
    factory_kwargs = {'extra': 1}

class AttackImageCreateView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = AttackImage
    inlines = [AttackItemInline]
    template_name = 'engine/attack_image_create.html'
    fields = ['title','image','source_url']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.creator = self.request.user
        f.hidden_data_found = attacks.spa(f.image)
        f.save()

class AttackItemCreateView(CreateView):
    model = AttackItem
    template_name = 'engine/attack_item_create.html'

    def formset_valid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.creator = self.request.user
        f.save()
```

As you can see I have 2 forms and only 1 form valid. I don't know how to deal with that. Here is my frontend code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 downdown whitebox">
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'attack_image_create' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}

  {% for formset in inlines %}
        {{ formset }}
      {% endfor %}

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

How should I be handling custom logic? Like saving the f.creator, saving finding and saving f.hidden_data_found, etc.

Link to package:
https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views

Edit: error:

null value in column "creator_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, test, attack_images/oatmeal.jpg, http://test.com, null).

Comment: The formset views provide `formset_valid`.

Comment: thanks, though I am still getting the error: null value in column "creator_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, test, attack_images/oatmeal.jpg, http://test.com, null).